# Memory warning results in crash when creating layers with images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, calayer

I'm creating an app which takes a photo each second and saves the image to the disk.
When enough photos has been taken, the app creates a video of the images using the AVFoundation framework. This is done by creating a layer for each image, add an animation which hides  the layer after some time then combine these layers into a single layer which is held by `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`.
After creating a `AVVideoComposition` which holds the animation tool, I will end up using `AVAssetExportSession` to export an `AVMutableComposition`.

However, while creating the layers my app will give two memeory warnings and then crash if I have 50-60 photos or more. I use the below code to create the layers. This means that for 60 images, the below loop will run 60 times. Once for each image. The `imageLayer` is created with the contents of the photo, an animation is applied to the layer and the layer is then added as a sublayer to `layer`.

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);

for (NSString *imagePath in imagePaths)
{
    CMTime endTime = CMTimeAdd(cursorTime, CMTimeMake(1.0f, (CGFloat)fps));

    UIImage *theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    CGFloat scaleFactor = MIN(renderSize.width / theImage.size.width, renderSize.height / theImage.size.height);
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(theImage.size.width * scaleFactor, theImage.size.height * scaleFactor);

    UIImage *resizedImage = [theImage resizedImageToSize:newSize];
    CGImageRef image = resizedImage.CGImage;
    CGSize imageSize = resizedImage.size;

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake((renderSize.width - imageSize.width) * 0.50f, (renderSize.height - imageSize.height) * 0.50f, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    imageLayer.bounds = CGRectMake((renderSize.width - imageSize.width) * 0.50f, (renderSize.height - imageSize.height) * 0.50f, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    imageLayer.contents = (__bridge id)image;
    imageLayer.beginTime = (CGFloat)cursorTime.value / (CGFloat)cursorTime.timescale;

    CABasicAnimation *hideAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"hidden"];
    hideAnimation.fromValue = @(NO);
    hideAnimation.toValue = @(YES);
    hideAnimation.additive = NO;
    hideAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    hideAnimation.beginTime = (CGFloat)endTime.value / (CGFloat)endTime.timescale;
    hideAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    [imageLayer addAnimation:hideAnimation forKey:nil];
    [layer addSublayer:imageLayer];

    cursorTime = endTime;
}
```

It seems to be this code which use too much memory. Can anyone tell me how I can optimize the code or in any other way avoid the memory warnings and ultimately avoid the crash?

**UPDATE** per Daij-Djans answer.

The autoreleasepool did not change a thing. I tried writing a custom layer and draw the image myself. This does allow me to render more images but it still ends up giving memory warnings and crashing the app.
It turns out that `-drawInContext:` is not called unless `-setNeedsDisplay` is called on the layer. The class looks like the following:

PhotoLayer.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface PhotoLayer : CALayer

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *path;

@end
```

PhotoLayer.m

```
#import "PhotoLayer.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

@implementation PhotoLayer

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    [super drawInContext:context];

    // Retrieve image from file path
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.path]);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, TRUE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image));

    // Create transformation for orientation
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL);
    CFDictionaryRef dictionaryRef = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
    CGAffineTransform transform;
    NSInteger orientation = [(NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionaryRef, kCGImagePropertyOrientation) integerValue];
    switch (orientation) {
        case 1:
            // Flip vertically
            transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height);
            break;
        case 3:
            // Flip horizontally
            transform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, self.bounds.size.width, 0.0f);
            break;
        case 6:
            // Rotate 90 degrees and flip vertically
            transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            break;
        case 8:
            // Rotate -90 degrees and flip vertically
            transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width);
            break;
        default:
            // Unknown orientation, consider landscape right
            transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height);
            NSLog(@"Unknown orientation when drawing image in layer.");
            break;
    }

    // Calculate amount to scale image
    CGFloat scaleFactor = MIN(self.bounds.size.width / imageSize.width, self.bounds.size.height / imageSize.height);

    // Calculate new size and positiondepending on orientation
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeZero;
    CGPoint pos = CGPointZero;
    if (orientation == 1 || orientation == 3)
    {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * scaleFactor, imageSize.height * scaleFactor);
        pos = CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.width - newSize.width) * 0.50f, (self.bounds.size.height - newSize.height) * 0.50f);
    }
    else
    {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        newSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.height * scaleFactor, imageSize.width * scaleFactor);
        pos = CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.height - newSize.width) * 0.50f, (self.bounds.size.width - newSize.height) * 0.50f);
    }

    // Apply transformation
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    // Draw image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, newSize.width, newSize.height), image);

    // Clean up
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CGImageRelease(image);
    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(dictionaryRef);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    _path = nil;
}

@end
```

I then use the layer like below. Instead of setting the contents of the layer, I set a path to the image and draw it. To draw it, I need to call `-setNeedsDisplay`.

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);

for (NSString *imagePath in imagePaths)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CMTime endTime = CMTimeAdd(cursorTime, CMTimeMake(1.0f, (CGFloat)fps));

        PhotoLayer *photoLayer = [[PhotoLayer alloc] init];
        photoLayer.path = imagePath;
        photoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);
        photoLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);
        photoLayer.beginTime = (CGFloat)cursorTime.value / (CGFloat)cursorTime.timescale;

        CABasicAnimation *hideAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"hidden"];
        hideAnimation.fromValue = @(NO);
        hideAnimation.toValue = @(YES);
        hideAnimation.additive = NO;
        hideAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        hideAnimation.beginTime = (CGFloat)endTime.value / (CGFloat)endTime.timescale;
        hideAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
        [photoLayer addAnimation:hideAnimation forKey:nil];
        [layer addSublayer:photoLayer];

        [photoLayer setNeedsDisplay];

        cursorTime = endTime;
    }
}

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, renderSize.width, renderSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:layer];
```

Answer (score 0):

when the number of imagePaths is large, for each imagePath you load the original, make a new resized image, a layer and an animation.

thats a lot of memory you accumulate over time.

1. you should try  and wrap the CONTENT of the loop inside an `@autoreleasepool {...}`

**IF** that is not enough,

I'd lazily load the images. Make a subclass of CALayer, pass it the url and then let it load it when it is displayed! (implement in drawInContext: in your subclaass

something like

```
 @MyURLLayer : CALayer
 @property(copy) NSString *path;
 @end

 @implementation MyURLLayer
 - (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    //load the image and draw it!
    //...
 }
 @end
```

---

BTW if you are not using arc you are leaking the originalImage and thats your prob

Comment: The autoreleasepool did not change anything. I tried drawing the images to the layers myself. This does allow me to render more images but ultimately I will receive memory warnings and the application will crash. It turns out that `-drawInContext:` is not called unless `-setNeedsDisplay` is called on the layer. I updated my question to show how I implemented the `CALayer` subclass. Please, if you have any other ideas, let me here. I'm really stuck on this issue.

Comment: There is clearly something wrong with my code. Instruments shows that when creating the layers the application uses more and more memory. I guess this is not expected. On the image, the small spikes are when images are taken. Then the rendering phase begins and the app keeps using memory. http://c.4su.re/PyIE

Comment: It seems to be `CGContextDrawImage` which doesn't release its memory. Does that sound right and would there be any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This will never work with a large amount of images. AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool requires the CAAnimation to be created which in turn will reference and hold the image data on the CALayer in memory. All of your images will than be in memory until the AVAssetExportSession either cancels, fails, or completes and is freed (or your application is shutdown from the watchdog which is more likely).

Unfortunately this is just a restraint of the export session. Interesting that AVAsset doesn't load it's data into memory until it is accessed but the animation tool does.

Only way to get around this is to do the transcoding of the images to video with something like AVAssetWriter and than once that has finished spawn the AVAssetExportSession if needed.